# Why CM_Register_Notification function not working

Tags: c++, windows, driver, visual-c++-2012

Using **[CM_Register_Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_register_notification)** function for receiving device change event.

returning  **#define CR_INVALID_DATA             (0x0000001F)**

I do not want to use  **RegisterDeviceNotification**  function for receiving device change event. So please do not suggest the above function.

```
int main()
{
CM_NOTIFY_FILTER cmNotifyFilter = { 0 };
cmNotifyFilter.cbSize = sizeof(cmNotifyFilter);
cmNotifyFilter.Flags = CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_DEVICE_INSTANCES;
cmNotifyFilter.FilterType = CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEHANDLE;
cmNotifyFilter.u.DeviceInterface.ClassGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT;

HCMNOTIFICATION hcm;

char *test = new char[1024]();

CONFIGRET configRet = ::CM_Register_Notification(&cmNotifyFilter, (PVOID)test, (PCM_NOTIFY_CALLBACK)&MyCMInterfaceNotification, &hcm);

if (configRet != CR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("CM_Register_Notification failed, error %d\n", (DWORD)configRet);
}
return 0;
} 

DWORD MyCMInterfaceNotification( HCMNOTIFICATION hNotify, PVOID Context, CM_NOTIFY_ACTION Action, PCM_NOTIFY_EVENT_DATA EventData,DWORD EventDataSize )
 {
   switch (Action) {
case CM_NOTIFY_ACTION_DEVICEINTERFACEARRIVAL:
    wprintf(("MyCmInterfaceNotification: Arrival of %S\n",
        EventData->u.DeviceInterface.SymbolicLink));

    //
    // Enqueue a work item to open target
    //

    break;
case CM_NOTIFY_ACTION_DEVICEINTERFACEREMOVAL:
    wprintf(("MyCmInterfaceNotification: removal of %S\n",
        EventData->u.DeviceInterface.SymbolicLink));
    break;
default:
    printf(("MyCmInterfaceNotification: Arrival unknown action\n"));
    break;
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you set `CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_*` flag, the member of `u` must be zeroes. also `CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_DEVICE_INSTANCES` - *This flag is only valid if `pFilter->FilterType` is `CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINSTANCE`.* but you use `FilterType = CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEHANDLE;` so you incompotible flags/type/data at once

Comment: really you need `Flags = 0;` and `FilterType = CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE;`

Comment: Hello RbMm, Tried with CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_VALID_FLAGS which is contains ( CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES | CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_DEVICE_INSTANCES),  pFilter->FilterType which are contains ( CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE | CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEHANDLE | CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINSTANCE | CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_MAX) & u with zeroes    but   Result with same error   CR_INVALID_DATA (0x0000001F).

Comment: read my second comment

Comment: Hello RbMm, executed the second comment but Result with same error CR_INVALID_DATA (0x0000001F).

Comment: i dont know how you do this, for me all ok

Comment: If Possible then Can you please share sample text file with code.

Comment: `CM_NOTIFY_FILTER cmNotifyFilter = { sizeof(cmNotifyFilter) };
 cmNotifyFilter.Flags = 0;
 cmNotifyFilter.FilterType = CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE;
 cmNotifyFilter.u.DeviceInterface.ClassGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT;`

Answer (score 0):

`CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEHANDLE` filter type is used for notification of device removals. When the device represented by the interface receives a remove query request, the system notifies your component.

You should call [CM_Register_Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_register_notification) with `DeviceHandle` set (handle of already opened device via `CreateFile` call) if you want to use this filter type:

```cpp
CM_NOTIFY_FILTER NotifyFilter = {0};
NotifyFilter.cbSize = sizeof(NotifyFilter);
NotifyFilter.FilterType = CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEHANDLE;
NotifyFilter.u.DeviceHandle.hTarget = Context->DeviceHandle;
```

But I guess you want to register for device interface arrival instead:

```cpp
CM_NOTIFY_FILTER NotifyFilter = {0};
NotifyFilter.cbSize = sizeof(NotifyFilter);
NotifyFilter.FilterType = CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE;
NotifyFilter.u.DeviceInterface.ClassGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT;
```

Here is example code for `CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE` callback:

```cpp
DWORD
WINAPI
InterfaceCallback(
    _In_ HCMNOTIFICATION       hNotify,
    _In_ PVOID                 hContext,
    _In_ CM_NOTIFY_ACTION      Action,
    _In_ PCM_NOTIFY_EVENT_DATA EventData,
    _In_ DWORD                 EventDataSize
    )
{
    switch (Action)
    {
    case CM_NOTIFY_ACTION_DEVICEINTERFACEARRIVAL:
        //
        // Register for device notifications
        //
        RegisterDeviceNotifications(EventData->u.DeviceInterface.SymbolicLink);
        break;

    case CM_NOTIFY_ACTION_DEVICEINTERFACEREMOVAL:
...
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

See [docs from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/registering-for-notification-of-device-interface-arrival-and-device-removal) for proper algorithm. And [official example code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/general/DCHU/osrfx2_DCHU_base/osrfx2_DCHU_usersvc/DeviceContext.cpp).